# Push New View controller with background color "clear"

Tags: ios, popover, pushviewcontroller

I have two view controllers oneVC.swift and twoVC.swift.
I want to show twoVC.swift on oneVC.swift as overlay with the background color of twoVC.swift as transparent. See the attachments.

[image: oneVC.swift]
[image: twoVC.swift]

I am trying with following code :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "twoVC") as! twoVC    
homeVC.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true;
homeVC.definesPresentationContext = true;
homeVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.navigationController!.present(homeVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

This code is working perfectly But the problem with the current code is that I can not further push any new controller from twoVC.swift since this is presented over oneVC.swift.
And if I use

> pushViewController

like this:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeVC, animated: false)
```

Using this I am not able to achieve the transparency of twoVC.swift.
So is there any possibility that i can push the second view controller over first view controller with transparency using

> pushViewController

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a `UIView` and overlaying it over oneVC? You can create a separate `.xib` and design it as you wish, then use the `UIView.transition` method to simulate the `UIViewController`'s push animation effect. Overlaying VCs is generally not the way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: Use delegation to inform oneVC that the user did something on twoVC.

Comment: you have to take one navigation controller before twoVC, connect that to twoVC and give it storyboard identifier, present that navigation controller as per normal code. So, from that navigation controller you can now push to other view controllers.

Comment: Problem lies in self.navigationController!.present(homeVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

My first `ViewController` is `PeopleViewController` and second one is `PopUpViewController` and also check image. My code is in objective c , you can convert into swift.[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNfh7.png)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

         PopUpViewController * popUp = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PopUpViewController"];

        popUp.nav=self.navigationController;

        [PeopleViewController setPresentationStyleForSelfController:self presentingController:popUp];

        [self presentViewController:popUp animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

+ (void)setPresentationStyleForSelfController:(UIViewController *)selfController presentingController:(UIViewController *)presentingController
    {
            presentingController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
            presentingController.definesPresentationContext = YES;

            [presentingController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
    }
```

Comment: But this technique has a drawback, we can further push any other controller.

Answer (score -1):

Problem lies in

`self.navigationController!.present(homeVC, animated: false, completion: nil)`.

This means that you are presenting homeVC over navigation controller. Presenting a view controller doesn't add it to navigation stack. So to fix this, you need to push homeVC rather than presenting it.

Comment: If you do that: it's absolutely impossible to "see" the one below, through a transparency.